# Can I generate redemption code in Apple Business Manager for my own app?

Tags: mdm, apple-business

For example I've created the app, set distribution method to 'Apple Business Manager' and my app has passed the review. Can I generate redemption code for my own app and share it with somebody?

Answer (score 1):

Not in 2021.

Currently redemption codes are generated from iTunes connect and not Apple Business Manager.